# Is this formulation of Modulo a Set?

Tags: agda, homotopy-type-theory, cubical-type-theory

The Cubical Agda library [defined a `Modulo` type like this](https://github.com/agda/cubical/blob/69ac45630ed55c4ae0445923d46c65bb67768f5d/Cubical/HITs/Modulo/Base.agda):

```
data Modulo (k : ℕ) : Type₀ where
  embed : (n : ℕ) → Modulo k
  pre-step : NonZero k → (n : ℕ) → embed n ≡ embed (k + n)
```

Is this a Set?

Hand-wavingly, I can see that any path is a composition of `refl`s and `pre-step`s, taking the form `embed n ≡ embed (m * k + n)`; and 
since `_+_` is associative and `0 +_ ≡ id`, the structure of how `refl`s and `pre-step`s are combined doesn't matter; but how would that be formalized?

Comment: You can import the [proof](https://github.com/agda/cubical/blob/69ac45630ed55c4ae0445923d46c65bb67768f5d/Cubical/HITs/Modulo/Properties.agda#L77) from the library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on @András Kovács's comment, turns out `Modulo n` is indeed a h-set and [there is a proof in the standard library](https://github.com/agda/cubical/blob/69ac45630ed55c4ae0445923d46c65bb67768f5d/Cubical/HITs/Modulo/Properties.agda), I just missed it :)

The proof basically goes like this:

- `Modulo 0` is isomorphic to `ℕ` since `NonZero 0` is empty (so we only have `embed` values).
- `Modulo (suc k)` is isomorphic to `Fin (suc k)` basically by applying enough `pre-step`s until we get `embed n` with `n < k`. [This is a long-winded technical proof taking up its own module](https://github.com/agda/cubical/blob/69ac45630ed55c4ae0445923d46c65bb67768f5d/Cubical/HITs/Modulo/FinEquiv.agda).

And then of course both `ℕ` and `Fin (suc k)` are discrete, hence h-sets themselves.